# Pandas Price Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good morning, I need help, I need to create an analysis that brings me the lowest value per line, and which supplier is the best value.

```
import pandas as pd
```

```
data = {'CODBAR':[29951,29952,29953],'DESCRI':['IPHONE 15','SAMSUNG S40','MOTOROLA G1000'],'PRICE_PROVIDER1':[1000.00,1200.00,1100.00],'PRICE_PROVIDER2':[999.00,1299.00,1199.00],'PRICE_PROVIDER3':[1199.00,1199.00,999.00]}
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
df.head()
```

```
CODBAR  DESCRI  PRICE_PROVIDER1 PRICE_PROVIDER2 PRICE_PROVIDER3
0   29951   IPHONE 15   1000.0  999.0   1199.0
1   29952   SAMSUNG S40 1200.0  1299.0  1199.0
2   29953   MOTOROLA G1000  1100.0  1199.0  999.0
```

I would like to find the lowest value line by line, and which supplier has the lowest value, and create a new dataframe with this data, so that we can proceed with the purchase order.
If anyone has any ideas, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way using `idxmin` to find the **column** with the minimum value for each row and `min` to find the minimum **value** for each row.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'CODBAR':[29951,29952,29953],'DESCRI':['IPHONE 15','SAMSUNG S40','MOTOROLA G1000'],'PRICE_PROVIDER1':[1000.00,1200.00,1100.00],'PRICE_PROVIDER2':[999.00,1299.00,1199.00],'PRICE_PROVIDER3':[1199.00,1199.00,999.00]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Select only the numerical columns
df_num = df.select_dtypes(include=['float64'])

# Find the column with the minimum value for each row
min_col = df_num.idxmin(axis=1)

# Find the minimum value itself
min_val = df_num.min(axis=1)

# Create a new dataframe with the CODBAR, DESCRI, and minimum value and provider
result = pd.DataFrame({'CODBAR': df['CODBAR'], 'DESCRI': df['DESCRI'], 'MIN_VALUE': min_val, 'PROVIDER': min_col})

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
   CODBAR          DESCRI  MIN_VALUE         PROVIDER
0   29951       IPHONE 15      999.0  PRICE_PROVIDER2
1   29952     SAMSUNG S40     1199.0  PRICE_PROVIDER3
2   29953  MOTOROLA G1000      999.0  PRICE_PROVIDER3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find several aggregates at once. You can throw in count, sum, mean, stdev, etc. Here is min & max.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'CODBAR':[29951,29952,29953],'DESCRI':['IPHONE 15','SAMSUNG S40','MOTOROLA G1000'],'PRICE_PROVIDER1':[1000.00,1200.00,1100.00],'PRICE_PROVIDER2':[999.00,1299.00,1199.00],'PRICE_PROVIDER3':[1199.00,1199.00,999.00]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

df[['PRICE_PROVIDER1', 'PRICE_PROVIDER2', 'PRICE_PROVIDER3']].agg(['min', 'max'])
```

[image]